# PHP: Failed to load resource

Tags: php, server

When using localhost(using php built in server) my php files load correctly and everything is displayed but when I upload it to an actual server and try to access it i'm getting the following error:

> GET http://shunterweb/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here's the PHP code

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../config.php');

// Get the DB connection settings
$dbHost = $config["db"]["server"]["host"];
$dbUser = $config["db"]["server"]["username"];
$dbPass = $config["db"]["server"]["password"];
$dbName = $config["db"]["server"]["dbname"];

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$dbName, "UID"=>$dbUser, "PWD"=>$dbPass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $dbHost, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT YardId,Yard FROM YWBYard"; 
$params = array();
$options = array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if( $result === false){
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }
}
else {
    $numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result); 
    //echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

    //display the results 
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['YardId']===1){
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://localhost:8080/".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }
        elseif($row['YardId']===2){
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://localhost:8080/bicker.php".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }
        else{
          echo "<li>"."<a href="."http://localhost:8080/crick.php".">".$row['Yard'],"</a></li>";
        }      
    }
}
//close the connection
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Is it something on my code or would this be server-side ?

Comment: Either or both. Check your error logs on the server box.

Comment: Check the error logs. apache and PHP error logs.

Comment: Likely something is not in the same place as it was when you were testing

Answer (score -4):

You might be getting warnings or fatal errors. To display all errors on server,

you need to write this line on header of the page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**OR**

```
error_reporting(1);
```

it will display all errors of php